# Evaluate postfix notation containing square, sine, log functions in it

Tags: postfix-mta

[Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWCO3.png)

^^^ Please see image attached first ^^^
We practiced how to evaluate funny arithmetic expressions like: 5+5*5 => 55+5*
Thing I don't understand here, how to treat sines, logs and square roots?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your example you dealing with [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Sines,logs and so on must be treated as a function call. Square is a usual operator with higher priority then sum or multiplication.

So for example sin(5) + (5 * (5 ^ 2)) will looks like
5 sin 5 5 2 ^ * +

P.S. In your example add and multiplication have same priority. Usually multiplication have higher priority so 5+5*5 -> 5 5 5 * +

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact answer to question, since this was a specific question "made up" by a professor.

In my case I had to treat functions like sin(), cos(), sqrt() as an unary operator (like a simple negation).